# attempt to set an attribute on NULL

Tags: r, data.table

```
Error in data.table::rbindlist(.data, ...) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

I am getting this error at:

```
FBInsightsExpanded <- list.stack(list.select(FBInsightsExpanded, website_purchase_roas = website_purchase_roas$action_link_click_destination));
  print(FBInsightsExpanded)
```

This is what the DF looks like. I am guessing I need to replace NULLs with NA's. But not able to get a fix for it so far

```
 website_purchase_roas  date_stop
1    0.673001 offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase, 6.506892 2018-10-11
2    1.369035 offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase, 0.594109 2018-10-11
3    2.084238                                           NULL 2018-10-11
4     1.31209                                           NULL 2018-10-11
5    2.337662                                           NULL 2018-10-11
6    0.996678                                           NULL 2018-10-11
7    1.936385 offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase, 1.482508 2018-10-11
8    2.777778                                           NULL 2018-10-11
9           0                                           NULL 2018-10-11
10   1.994885                                           NULL 2018-10-11
11   2.402023                                           NULL 2018-10-11
12   4.635056 offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase, 5.222421 2018-10-11
13          0                                           NULL 2018-10-11
14   1.990291                                           NULL 2018-10-11
15   6.557377                                           NULL 2018-10-11
16   3.703704                                           NULL 2018-10-11
17   3.038936                                           NULL 2018-10-11
```

Here's what the code looks like:

```
library(httr)
library(fbRads)
library(rlist)
library(rhdfs)
library(Rfacebook)
library(SocialMediaLab)
library(dplyr)


app <- oauth_app('facebook', 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
fbacc <- fbad_init(accountid = id, token = "token", version = '3.0')


FBInsightsExpanded <- fb_insights(level = 'ad',
                                        time_range=sprintf("{'since':%s,'until':%s}", paste('"', maxDate, '"', sep=''), paste('"', yesterdayDate, '"', sep='')), time_increment= 1  ,                        
                                        fields = toJSON(c("impressions",
                                                  "date_start",
                                                  "reach",
                                                  "frequency", 
                                                  "ad_name",
                                                  "adset_name", 
                                                  "campaign_name", 
                                                  "clicks",
                                                  "cpc",
                                                  "cpm",
                                                  "cpp",
                                                  "ctr",
                                                  "objective",
                                                  "spend", 
                                                  "account_name",
                                                  "ad_id",
                                                  "adset_id",
                                                  "buying_type",
                                                  "campaign_id",
                                                  "canvas_avg_view_time",
                                                  "cost_per_unique_click",
                                                  "inline_link_click_ctr",
                                                  "social_spend",
                                                  "total_action_value",
                                                  "unique_clicks",
                                                  "unique_ctr",
                                                  "website_purchase_roas")));


  FBInsightsExpanded <- list.stack(list.select(FBInsightsExpanded, website_purchase_roas = website_purchase_roas$value));
```

** Edit: packagelist and relevant bits of code as suggested

Comment: I don't know how you expect people to help you, when you present code with functions from some unknown package and no context regarding why you are using `<<-`. You need to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: updated/..........

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that Facebook is giving you JSON in a list format? If you want a data frame you first need to unpack it from the list, but that's a separate topic from your original question.

In terms of your original question, there's a pretty easy way to do that with the is_empty() function from `purrr`. It's not clear what the column with the NULL values in your original example is called, so I am going to call it **value**, and the data frame **fb_data**.

Here you go:

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)

fb_data <- fb_data %>%
    mutate(value = ifelse(is_empty(value) == TRUE,NA,value))
```

Here's what you are doing in this: you are checking if the row in the value column is empty (i.e. NULL) and if that is true, you are changing it to NA, otherwise you are leaving it alone.

Comment: What is the advantage of `is_empty` over `is.null`?

Comment: Probably not much difference in this case, tbh! I guess I just tend to use `tidyverse` tools over base R.

Comment: @RandallHelms: I get   no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: Yes, that's because Facebook gave you a list, as I mentioned at the beginning of my comment. You need to convert from a list to a data frame. If this is something you've never done before, have a look at this: https://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-list-to-a-data-frame/